# How can I process data in parts to prevent Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: plugins, php

In a Wordpress plugin I am trying to copy bulk posts all at once. This takes a long time for complicated posts with lots of settings and content etc , is there a way to break up the process into groups similarly to how wordpress plugins and themes bulk update works. Like could I copy some post ids into a queue and process them, before proceeding with another queue. Or something like that?

Comment: doing this will require multiple requests, but you can skip the max execution time by using CLI instead of browser requests. AJAX or cron jobs will be useful to look into here. It's also very possible to run into the max execution time updating themes and plugins if you update a lot of them